# prevent multiple hits to database in django templates

Tags: django

I have my model Task

```
class Task(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    ...
```

and also my models Member, from auth...

```
class Member(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    def get_num_tasks(self):
        return self.task_set.all().count()
```

finally I have my template like this where I want to show how many tasks got this member... but if is it greater than zero then add a class...

```
<p {% if user.get_num_tasks > 0 %} class="green" {% endif %}>{{ user.get_num_tasks }}</p>
```

The problem here is that every time I load my template it hits the database twice, one for check if is it greater than zero and one more for show the number...

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`with` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

```
{% with task_count=user.get_num_tasks %}
    <p {% if task_count > 0 %} class="green" {% endif %}>{{ task_count }}</p>
{% endwith %}
```

> Edit: I had to remove the spaces before and after
>   the assignment (task_count = user.get_num_tasks), otherwise it crashes.

Comment: thank you... anyway I had to remove the spaces before and after the assignment...

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer, so it can help others in the future